# Divergence theorem and exercise with the cone

Tags: calculus

The problem is given as follows.

Let $S$ be a surface defined by $\mathbb{r}(u,v)=<2uv, u^2-v^2 ,u^2 +v^2>,~~u^2+v^2 \le1$ and let $\textbf{F}(x,y,z)=<x,y,-z>$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Evaluate the flux $\int_{S} \mathbf{F}\bullet d {\mathbb{\sigma}}$ where $S$ is oriented upward.

When I used Divergence theorem, I got $-\frac{4\pi}{3}$.
However, the answer is $-\frac{8\pi}{3}$ when I take the direct computation
of the surface integral.

I want to know why this happens.

Comment: The divergence theorem should be applied on closed surface right ?
Could you also provide us the work you did ?

Comment: @Zubzub I think the questioner added the disk $x^2+y^2 \le1, z=1$ to construct the closed surface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the parameterization of cone.

Given map $\mathbb{r}$ is not injective.

$\mathbb{r}(u,v)=\mathbb{r}(w,z)$ $\Rightarrow$ $(u,v)=±(w,z)$.

In other words, we sweep out the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},~~x^2+y^2 \le1$, twice exactly.

In many differential geometry textbooks, the parameterization of the surface should be one to one. Above difference of results of two methods comes from the error.